# Use TwoWayGridView with ListViewAnimations

Tags: android, listview, animation, gridview

I would like to use the [TwoWayGridView by jess-anders](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview/) with the [ListViewAnimationsLibrary by nhaarman](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)

The main problem is that in order to use the AnimationsAdapter from the ListViewAnimationsLibrary you have to call setAbsListView on the Adapter. But since none of the TwoWayGridView classes are extending AbsListView I can't set the TwoWayGridWay as the AbsListView of the AnimationAdapter.

Is there an other way to do this which I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ListViewAnimations` does not support classes that do not extend `AbsListView`.

The library depends on certain methods included in the contract of the `AbsListView` class, which might not be provided by the custom classes `TwoWayGridView` provides. You might get it to work, but you would need to alter the source code to accept their classes instead of an `AbsListView`.